# If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with Euler prime $q$, does $I(n^2) \geq 5/3$ imply $k=1$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, conjectures, perfect-numbers

Let $\sigma(x)$ denote the sum of the divisors of $x \in \mathbb{N}$.  Denote the *abundancy index* of $y \in \mathbb{N}$ by $I(y)=\sigma(y)/y$.

If $\sigma(N)=2N$, then $N$ is said to be *perfect*.

Euler proved that every *odd perfect number* has the form $q^k n^2$ where $q$ is prime (called the *Euler prime*) with $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

If $k=1$, then since $q \geq 5$, then we have
$$I(q)I(n^2)=2 \Longleftrightarrow I(n^2)=\dfrac{2q}{q+1} \geq \dfrac{5}{3}.$$

If $k>1$, then we can use the bound
$$I(q^k) < \dfrac{q}{q-1} \leq \dfrac{5}{4}$$
so that
$$I(n^2)=\dfrac{2}{I(q^k)} > \dfrac{2(q-1)}{q} \geq \dfrac{8}{5}.$$

Here is my question:

> If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with Euler prime $q$, does $I(n^2) \geq 5/3$ imply $k=1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We consider three cases:

**Case 1** $I(n^2) = 5/3$

This implies that
$$2 - I(n^2) = \frac{2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)}{n^2} = 2 - \frac{5}{3} = \frac{1}{3},$$
which implies that $(2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)) \mid n^2$, since
$$\frac{n^2}{2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)} = 3$$
then holds.  This means that $n^2$ is deficient-perfect, which is true if and only if $k=1$ [(Dris [2017], pages 17 to 18)](http://nntdm.net/volume-23-2017/number-2/12-20/).

**Case 2** $I(n^2) < 5/3$

Since $k = 1 \implies I(n^2) \geq 5/3$ holds, by the contrapositive, we have
$$I(n^2) < 5/3 \implies k > 1.$$

Thus, $k > 1$.

**Case 3** $I(n^2) > 5/3$

Since we have the inequality
$$I(n^2) \leq \frac{2q}{q+1}$$
with equality if and only if $k=1$, then we have $q>5$ under this case.

Next, since $q$ is the special/Euler prime (satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$), then $q>5$ implies that $q \geq 13$.

So we now have
$$I(q^k) < \frac{q}{q-1} \leq \frac{13}{12}$$
and therefore that
$$I(n^2) = \frac{2}{I(q^k)} > \frac{24}{13}.$$

From the other answer, we have
$$I(n^2) = \dfrac{2{q^k}(q - 1)}{q^{k+1} - 1} = 2 - 2\dfrac{q^k - 1}{q^{k+1} - 1}.$$
Thus, we obtain
$$\frac{2}{13} > 2 - I(n^2) = 2\dfrac{q^k - 1}{q^{k+1} - 1}$$
$$q^{k+1} - 1 > 13q^k - 13$$
$$q^{k+1} - 13q^k + 12 > 0.$$
This last inequality does not force $k=1$, and neither proves that $k>1$.

Answer (score 0):

In an answer to a related [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1864365), we get that
$$I(n^2) = \dfrac{2{q^k}(q - 1)}{q^{k+1} - 1} = 2 - 2\dfrac{q^k - 1}{q^{k+1} - 1}.$$

Then $I(n^2) \geq 5/3$ implies that
$$2 - 2\dfrac{q^k - 1}{q^{k+1} - 1} \geq \dfrac{5}{3}$$
$$\dfrac{1}{6} \geq \dfrac{q^k - 1}{q^{k+1} - 1}$$
$$q^{k+1} - 6q^k + 5 \geq 0,$$
which does **not** force $k=1$.

$k=1$ *does follow* if it is known *a priori* that $q=5$.  In this case, $I(n^2) \geq 5/3$ and $q=5$ imply that $I(n^2)=5/3$.

**UPDATE (September 03 2017 - Manila time)**

Suppose that $k > 1$, so that we have $k \geq 5$ (since $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$).  We are given that
$$\frac{2}{I(q^k)}=I(n^2) \geq \frac{5}{3}.$$
It follows that
$$I(q^k) \leq \frac{6}{5},$$
whereupon we obtain
$$I(q^5) \leq I(q^k) \leq \frac{6}{5}.$$
It follows that
$$\frac{q^6 - 1}{q^6 - q^5} = \frac{q^6 - 1}{{q^5}(q - 1)} \leq \frac{6}{5}.$$
Consequently, since $q \geq 5 > 1$, we have
$$5q^6 - 5 = 5(q^6 - 1) \leq 6(q^6 - q^5) = 6q^6 - 6q^5$$
which implies that
$$q^6 - 6q^5 + 5 \geq 0.$$
When $q=5$, we obtain
$$q^6 - 6q^5 + 5 = {q^5}(q - 6) + 5 = {5^5}\cdot(-1) + 5 < 0.$$